karate.log files are not generating
I found similar question but it was not helpful for me. I am running the karate feature files from a runner:
void testParallel() throws IOException {
    Runner.path("classpath:Features/abc.feature")
            .tags("@abc")
            .hook(new ReportportalHook())
            .parallel(1);
}

Now after it executes there is no log file generated in the target folder. What is going wrong here?
I have logback-test.xml file copied from here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/logback-test.xml to my project at the runner level under src/test/java
src/test/java
 |
 |--feature--abc.feature
 |--TestRunner.java    
 |--logback-test.xml    

Edit:
I am also getting this error:
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/C:/Users/myComp/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/E:/workspace/proj/Final/lib/DigitalSigner.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/E:/workspace/proj/Final/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
And this is the pom file:
<dependency>
  <groupId>slf4j-api-1.7.5</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api-1.7.5</artifactId>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5</artifactId>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>


follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

what files or information should I add here?

read the above link all the way to the end. but you can wait, someone else may have the time and patience to help you given the information you provided

this issue got resolved ; turns out updating slf4j version to latest worked for me.
